# preferable way to get map's value in javascript

Tags: javascript

As far as I know you can get map's value by key in two ways:

```js
var myMap = {a: 1, b: 2}
var firstWay = myMap.a
var secondWay = myMap['a']
```

Which way is preferable? Is there a convection for this? Should I avoid first way and could be there any problems I may find in the future (e.g  IE may not support it)? **I understand that if I had some keys which require text escaping I won't be able to use .value on the map object, but what about simple cases?**

My subjective point of view is that first way looks better.

Comment: Use dot notation if you know the propertie's name, and brackets [] if it's a variable property name.

Comment: The way you've now edited your question makes it entirely subjective and calls for an opinion.  If that's all your question is now about, then it is considered off-topic here and should be closed.  I provided an answer below BEFORE you edited your question to be purely about opinion.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I edited it, but I merely highlighted a sentence that was there all along. I did that because I noticed your (and Dmitry's) answers which seemed to ignore that.

Comment: OK, then your question should be closed as "primarily opinion-based" since you aren't asking for any actual programming reasons to choose one over the other.  I'm voting to close as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: @jfriend00 - I agree with you, it should be closed

Comment: I provided an answer about when to choose one over the other for programming reasons (which I have since deleted).  You rejected that as an interesting answer so nothing else is left besides opinion, I guess.

Comment: @jfriend00 - don't confuse. I commented on your answer, I edited the question, but I didn't ask it originally :-) I'm with you on the close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically the only difference is that you can use the `[property]` syntax even if you don't know the property name. E.g.:

```
property = 'a'
myMap[property] // results in 1
```

Otherwise just use the dot notation.

Also some people use a convention that you use the dot notation for your own data, but use brackets to access data retrieved from some external source.

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking.

Comment: "No" is an answer too, now the OP knows that he can use whatever he likes more, as there is no significant difference in simple cases.

Comment: The OP asks ***"Which way is preferable?"***.  When you remove programming reasons for selecting one over the other which it appears the question does, nothing is left but opinion which makes the question off-topic for here.  If you want to try an answer that "there is no preference", then you can do that, but that's not what your answer is now.

Comment: He also asks *Should I avoid first way and could be there any problems I may find in the future?*. That's a valid question, while I haven't answered it.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the dot notation requires the property name to be an identifierName. For example:

```
obj["a-b"]; // ok
obj.a-b;    // fail! Parsed as `(obj.a) - b`
```

Moreover, before ECMAScript 5, the dot notation only allowed identifiers. That is, it excluded reservedWords. Then,

```
obj.class; // ok in ES5+
obj.class; // fail on old browsers
```

So in those cases you might prefer the bracket notation.

Otherwise it doesn't matter.